# MySql jdbc driver loaded as version 3 instead of version 4

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Driver version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.7
After some code loading the driver, there is a check

```
Connection con = getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
System.out.println("JDBC major version: " + meta.getJDBCMajorVersion());
```

And output shows
JDBC major version: 3

2 questions:

1. How do I make it work as if it was version 4?
2. Does it really matter?

Comment: I edited your question and replaced _type_ with _version_, because type 3 / type 4 has a specific meaning in JDBC, and is not related to the JDBC (major) version.

Comment: Side note: why are you using the ancient version 5.1.7? The latest version is 5.1.38.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel because that's an ancient app :) upgrade to higher version is out of scope right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: there is a bug in this version :( 
[Bug #55217     DatabaseMetaData.getJDBCMajorVersion() returns 3 instead of 4](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55217)